# Dedicated to our #1 Fan

Tags: riddle, cryptic-clues

> People tend to think of me as being small.
>   However I can be confused with an imaginary large being.
>   It has been said a saint got me right between the eyes, perhaps, next to America.
>   I persistently worry when I move about the snake's head.
>   In the West, I am a wealthy and influential businessman.
>   In the mysterious East, I become dull.
>   Whenever I enter a city in São Paulo, I am reminded of the French Revolution.
>   Whenever I come back, there is a very strong smell.

**Who am I?**
**Please explain each line in your answer.**

Answer (score 12, accepted):

People tend to think of me as being small.

> A **gnat** is a small flying insect.

However I can be confused with an imaginary large being.

> Sounds like a **[nat](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nat_(spirit))**, a spirit worshipped in Myanmar, of which there are 37 Great Nats.

It has been said a saint got me right between the eyes, perhaps, next to America.

> Ignatius - the Saint, has gnat between two **i**'s, next to the **US**. Credit to Stiv for this.

I persistently worry when I move about the snake's head.

> **angst** - constant worry, includes **s**nake's head in my anagram.

In the West, I am a wealthy and influential businessman.

> **magnate** -  gnat inside Mae (West) the actress.

In the mysterious East, I become dull.

> **stagnate** - to become dull, is mixed East & gnat.

Whenever I enter a city in São Paulo, I am reminded of the French Revolution.

> **assignats**  - paper money issued during the French Revolution. Gnat in [Assis](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Assis), a city in São Paulo.

Whenever I come back, there is a very strong smell.

> **tang** - (gnat reversed) is a refreshingly sharp aroma or flavor.

Title: Dedicated to our #1 Fan

> Stack Exchange user gnat is the highest voter on our site - and they're all upvotes!

Comment: Just beat me to it! Your missing saint is rot13(vtangvh - forgjrra gur v'f, arkg gb 'hf')

Comment: @Stiv - oh you could (have) post(ed). Thank you for this info!

Comment: No worries, would rather your answer was complete than trying to score points off a one-line partial! :) +1

Comment: They're all upvotes because he doesn't have enough rep for any other kind of vote ;-)

Comment: Honestly at this point he deserves to get more rep just for the upvotes he's given